# How to apply multiple functions to a dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to apply multiple functions to my pandas dataframes, which is being called from other internal scripts. However, when applying them, the code get really long and I think that isn't a good engineering practice in general:

```
df['data_udo_product_brand_mode'] = df['data_udo_product_brand'].fillna(
        '[]').apply(think_preprocessing.create_list).apply(think_math.get_mode).apply(lambda x: x.strip('"').lower())
```

Is there a more efficient and better way to apply multiple functions to a dataframe/dataframe columns than the above way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want some form of `agg`, but it's unclear what you're asking without seeing some code

Comment: unless your code is running slowly, I think this kind of daisy chaining is part of the design of `pandas`.  You can split the call onto multiple lines for clarity --> `df.function1().\  newline function2().\ newlink .. etc

Comment: I just looked this up, and found some best practices to make the code more readable -> I guess lambda functions are the fastest way to apply functions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there may be a way, but one thing can be done here that the lambda function can be separated out so to get rid from the code getting long .For example:

```
#Lowering character and removing spaces
strip_lower = lambda x: x.strip('"').lower()

df['data_udo_product_brand_mode']=df['data_udo_product_brand'].fillna('[]').apply(think_preprocessing.create_list).apply(think_math.get_mode).apply(strip_lower)
```